# Create a flag "Y" in an Excel matrix - "Ideas" as rows and "Domains" as columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, automation

I have this final output, I want to achieve in Excel.

[image: final output]

I need help with automation of the flagging "Y". Ideas are rows and Domains are Columns.

My Raw data tab in Excel has many more columns than shown below. Below are the columns I need for Ideas and Domains matrix.

| Summary | Custom field (Platform Domain) | Custom field (Platform Domain) | Custom field (Platform Domain) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Idea A | Domain 16 | Domain 20 | Domain 25 |
| Idea B | Domain 11 |  |  |
| Idea C | Domain 21 |  |  |
| Idea D | Domain 7 |  |  |

Depending on the idea, there could be more "Custom field (Platform Domain)" columns for every data refresh.

I have tried using functions like `IF()`, `SEARCH()`, and `IFERROR()` along with conditional formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

```
=IF(SUM(($A9=$A$2:$A$5)*(B$8=$B$2:$D$5)),"Y","")
```

---

**Note:** You would need to change the range and cell references as per your data

---

Or, Spill the output all at once using `LAMBDA()` helper function `MAKEARRAY()`

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _r, A9:A12,
     _c, B8:AK8,
     MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_r),COLUMNS(_c),LAMBDA(r,c,IF(SUM((INDEX(_r,r)=A2:A5)*(INDEX(_c,c)=B2:C5)),"Y",""))))
```

---

BTW, instead of using `Conditional Formatting` use `Custom Formatting` it takes less space and excel will work more faster.

[image]

---

```
=SUM(($A9=$A$2:$A$5)*(B$8=$B$2:$D$5))
```

---

Custom format cells by `[Blue][=1] "Y";;` although it wont highlight cells by the background color bt you can have highlighted fonts.

---

Or Use `REPT()`

```
=REPT("Y",SUM(($A9=$A$2:$A$5)*(B$8=$B$2:$D$5)))
```

---

The following `MAKEARRAY()` function has been named as `FLIP()` it not only transforms the whole array into desired output, but also does the required output needed, however few relevant things we usually ignore, it returns a **SORTED** headers as well as doesn't create a **DUPLICATE** headers for the domains(as there may or may not be duplicate entries for domains). Watch the .gif

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A8</kbd>

```
=FLIP(RawData)
```

---

The formula is defined in name manager as `FLIP()`

```
=LAMBDA(table,      
        LET(
            _data, table,     
            _ideas, TAKE(_data,,1),      
            _domains, DROP(_data,,1),     
            _temp, UNIQUE(TOROW(_domains,1),1),      
            _sort, SORTBY(_temp, TEXTAFTER(_temp," ")/1),      
            _r, ROWS(_ideas),      
            _c, COLUMNS(_sort),      
            _databody, HSTACK(_ideas,MAKEARRAY(_r,_c,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(SUM((INDEX(_ideas,r)=_ideas)*(INDEX(_sort,c)=_domains)),"Y",0)))),      
            _headers, HSTACK("",_sort),      
            VSTACK(_headers,_databody)))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can use horizontal lookup (`HLOOKUP`) to check if the Domain is in one of the columns of your idea. If not, leave it empty, otherwise put "Y" there.

In this example I am using this formula:
`=IF(ISNA(HLOOKUP(H$1,$B2:$D2,1,0)),"","Y")` which you can drag around your target table.

[image]

Use conditional formatting to give the 'Y' cells an orange background.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that writes the whole set to the sheet:

```vb
=LET(data,A2:D5,
domains,SORT(TOROW(DROP(data,,1),1),,,TRUE),
idx,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
result,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(data),COLUMNS(domains),
                 LAMBDA(r,d,IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(INDEX(domains,,d),CHOOSEROWS(data,r),0)),"Y",""))),
HSTACK(VSTACK("",CHOOSECOLS(data,1)),VSTACK(domains,result)))
```

If you have a complete list of domains, you could set that range for the `domains`-parameter.

[image]